# Want to parse WSDL file and update the result in .xsd file

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xsd, wsdl

I have a wsdl file, which i want to parse. And want the schema output in different XSD files.

For EX:

Below is the schema part of my WSDl

```
<xs:complexType name="AInqRq">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="ANo" type="acct:ANo"/>
            <xs:element name="CNo" type="card:CNo"/>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="OCode" type="acct:OCode"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="ANo">
        <xs:restriction base="ty:ANo"/>

    <xs:simpleType name="CNo">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>

    <xs:simpleType name="OCode">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>

<xs:simpleType name="ANo">
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
```

Output which i want is AInqRq.xsd and content should be as below, replacing the hierarchy with simple type:

```
<xs:complexType name="AInqRq">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="ANo" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="CNo" type="xs:string"/>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="OCode" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
```

I have tried to parse and able to get the content as a operation name, complexelement name, but not able to get the output in above format. Please some one can help on the same.

I need XSD file only. Also i am using concrete wsdl, so all the elements and their structure is defined within the single file.

Comment: Also please note that i am using WSDL file and parsing to get the output in XSD file.

Comment: Using JAVA, forgot to mentioned above.